# how does java.math.RoundingMode work?

Tags: java, rounding

I'm having trouble with rounding. Specifically, after reading all the javadoc, I was expecting the following code:

```
int n = (integer between 0 and 9, included)
new BigDecimal(n + 0.555d).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue()
```

to return `n + 0.56`. Instead, these are the return values for `n` from `0` to `4`:

```
 new BigDecimal(0.555d).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue()
 0.56
 new BigDecimal(1.555d).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue()
 1.55
 new BigDecimal(2.555d).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue()
 2.56
 new BigDecimal(3.555d).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue()
 3.56
 new BigDecimal(4.555d).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue()
 4.55
```

I have also tried to change the rounding mode:

```
int n = (integer between 0 and 9, included)
new BigDecimal(n + 0.555d).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN).doubleValue()
```

expecting `n + 0.55` as a result for each and every `n`. Instead, the return values are exactly the same as the previous example:

```
 new BigDecimal(0.555d).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN).doubleValue()
 0.56
 new BigDecimal(1.555d).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN).doubleValue()
 1.55
 new BigDecimal(2.555d).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN).doubleValue()
 2.56
 new BigDecimal(3.555d).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN).doubleValue()
 3.56
 new BigDecimal(4.555d).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN).doubleValue()
 4.55
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem you have is that double is not a precise representation and you are round based on this imprecise number.

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(1.555d);
System.out.println("bd=" + bd);
bd = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println("after rounding bd=" + bd);
double d = bd.doubleValue();
System.out.println("after rounding d=" + d);
```

prints

```
bd=1.5549999999999999378275106209912337362766265869140625
after rounding bd=1.55
after rounding d=1.55
```

however

```
BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(1.555d);
System.out.println("bd=" + bd);
bd = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println("after rounding bd=" + bd);
double d = bd.doubleValue();
System.out.println("after rounding d=" + d);
```

prints

```
bd=1.555
after rounding bd=1.56
after rounding d=1.56
```

This works because `BigDecimal.valueOf` does some extra rounding based on how double would appear if you printed it.

---

However I wouldn't use BigDecimal unless performance/simplicity is not an issue.

```
double d = 1.555d;
System.out.println("d=" + d);
d = roundToTwoPlaces(d);
System.out.println("after rounding d=" + d);

public static double roundToTwoPlaces(double d) {
    return ((long) (d < 0 ? d * 100 - 0.5 : d * 100 + 0.5)) / 100.0;
}
```

prints

```
d=1.555
after rounding d=1.56
```

For more details [Double your money again](http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/08/double-your-money-again.html) compares the performance of different ways of rounding.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was sure I was forgetting about something but couldn't quite point out the problem.

Comment: I was running my unit tests and it wasn't making sense the values returned with the double rounding half up. But with BigDecimal everything start working.

Answer (score 3):

@Peter Lawrey I looked at your examples and wrote a quick program comparing the simple approach that you posted along with all the methods for RoundingMode.  The code is here for anyone interested, this will clearly show the differences:

[RoundingMode.java] https://gitlab.com/bobby.estey/java/-/blob/master/maven/jdk14/src/main/java/mathematics/RoundingModeExamples.java

```
Results:
lowDouble:                             1.55553
simple - lowDouble:                    1.5555
RoundingMode.UP - lowDouble:           1.5556
RoundingMode.DOWN - lowDouble:         1.5555
RoundingMode.CEILING - lowDouble:      1.5556
RoundingMode.FLOOR - lowDouble:        1.5555
RoundingMode.HALF_UP - lowDouble:      1.5555
RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN - lowDouble:    1.5555
RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN - lowDouble:    1.5555
highDouble:                            1.55555
simple - highDouble:                   1.5556
RoundingMode.UP - highDouble:          1.5556
RoundingMode.DOWN - highDouble:        1.5555
RoundingMode.CEILING - highDouble:     1.5556
RoundingMode.FLOOR - highDouble:       1.5555
RoundingMode.HALF_UP - highDouble:     1.5555
RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN - highDouble:   1.5555
RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN - highDouble:   1.5555
```

Comment: page not found :/

Answer (score 2):

`0.555d` is a `double` value.  It may be slightly larger than 0.555 or slightly smaller.

Answer (score 2):

Rounding mode use for Round the Decimal Value.

You can use with.

```
double DecimalValue = 3.1452;
BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(DecimalValue).setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN);
```

=>

```
 RoundingMode.CEILING
```

Rounding mode to round towards positive infinity. For 
 positive values this rounding mode behaves as UP, for 
 negative values as DOWN. 
Rule: `x.round() >= x`

```
RoundingMode.DOWN
```

Rounding mode where the values are rounded towards 
 zero. 
Rule: `x.round().abs() <= x.abs()`

```
RoundingMode.DOWN
```

Rounding mode to round towards negative infinity. For 
 positive values this rounding mode behaves as DOWN, for 
 negative values as UP. 
Rule: `x.round() <= x`

```
RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN
```

Rounding mode where values are rounded towards the 
 nearest neighbor. Ties are broken by rounding down.

```
RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN
```

Rounding mode where values are rounded towards the 
 nearest neighbor. Ties are broken by rounding to the even 
 neighbor.

```
RoundingMode.HALF_UP
```

Rounding mode where values are rounded towards the 
 nearest neighbor. Ties are broken by rounding up.

```
 RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY
```

Rounding mode where the rounding operations throws an 
 `ArithmeticException` for the case that rounding is 
 necessary, i.e. for the case that the value cannot be 
 represented exactly.

```
RoundingMode.UP
```

Rounding mode where positive values are rounded 
 towards positive infinity and negative values towards 
 negative infinity. 
Rule: `x.round().abs() >= x.abs()`