# Decimal Format Rounding Mode produces inconsistent values

Tags: java, double, precision, decimalformat

I've found that using the decimal format and rounding mode shown behaves unexpectedly with some values

```
    double b = 123.135;
    //double b = 1896.675;
    //double b = 523.135;

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
    df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(b);
    String a = df.format(b);
    System.out.println(a);

    double roundOff = Math.round(b * 100.0) / 100.0;
    System.out.println(roundOff);
```

Produces:

```
123.135
123.14
123.14
```

Which I believe to be correct.

While using this value: 1896.675 produces the following:

```
1896.675
1896.67
1896.68
```

Which I regard as unexpected - What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Setting BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(b); and printing bd results in 1896.674999999999954525264911353588104248046875 which I guess is close to the actual value stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem here is that it is not possible to store all possible fractions in a variable because of the limitations of the binary format. So basically double just approximates the value you entered and thats why rounding errors occure.
You can read more about this topic in for example this thread: [how does java.math.RoundingMode work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124448/how-does-java-math-roundingmode-work)

Long story short, if you want precise rounding use BigDecimal (and the valueOf Function of the BigDecimal class)

Comment: Note that even BigDecimal only gives exact results if every number involved can be exactly represented as a decimal fraction. It cannot represent exactly, for example, the result of dividing 1 by 3.