# Java - Round off to two decimal place based on the third decimal value

Tags: java

I have been sitting on this for a day now thinking like a 5th grade school student.

```
public class Tester 
{                                                          
    static String actualValue = "";
    private static DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");  //To round off to two decimal places.
    static double regPrice = 0.0;
    static double regPrice2 = 0.0;
    
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
          regPrice2 = 1506.365;
          
          System.out.println("reg price 1 is: "+regPrice2);
          System.out.println("reg price 1 after rounding is is: "+round(regPrice2));
          
          regPrice = 8535.765;
          
          System.out.println("reg price  is: "+regPrice);
          System.out.println("reg price  after rounding is: "+round(regPrice));
      }
     
     public static double round(double value) 
        {         
            df2.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            String returnValue = df2.format(value);
            double actualValue = Double.parseDouble(returnValue);
            return actualValue;   
        }
    
}
```

| Output | Value 1 | Value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Actual | 1506.37 | 8535.**76** |
| Expected | 1506.37 | 8535.**77** |

Why is the rounding off working for the first number but not the second?
How can I make this work?

Comment: (Unrelated) [Do not use floating point types for monetary amounts.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/982149)

Comment: What is the output of line `System.out.println("reg price  is: "+regPrice);` ?

Comment: reg price 1 is: 1506.365

reg price 1 after rounding is is: 1506.37

reg price  is: 8535.765

reg price  after rounding is: 8535.76

Comment: Is it _really_? I'd expect it to be 8535.76499999999999999999995874871 or something like that.

Comment: I get your value when I do regPrice2 = new BigDecimal(1506.365);  But when I use double, it prints 8535.765

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank to the floating-pointrepresentation, what you think 1506.365 or 8535.765 is actually number slightly greater or less than you expect. The floating-point numbers are represented as mantissa and exponent. Hence for example for 0.365 and 0.765 rounding is done differently. Rounding near halves then appears as in random direction. Use `BigDecimal` if you need a precise number.

Comment: This is interesting. 

regPrice2 = new BigDecimal(1506.365);
regPrice = new BigDecimal(8535.765);

prints :
```
reg price 1 is: 1506.365000000000009094947017729282379150390625
reg price 1 after rounding is is: 1506.37 
reg price  is: 8535.764999999999417923390865325927734375
reg price  after rounding is: 8535.76
```
My requirement is to get 8535.76. How to achieve that?

Comment: Your comment combined with the suggestions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124448/how-does-java-math-roundingmode-work gave me the solution. Thanks. :)